# NGINX does not return 404 on wrong pages

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am trying to find out why my website is not returning me a 404 on non-existent urls.
For example, I don't have a `mydomain.com/contacts` url, but the link still returns it.

My goal is to let only the main url ("/") to be accessible.
Every other url should return 404 (or better 301) and every parameter request (such as `/?_escaped_fragment_=`) to return 301.

Here is a piece of my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}
http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;

        server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;
        server_name www.example.com;

        return 301 $scheme://example.com/;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;
        server_name crowdrobot.ru;

        location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://11.11.111.111:5000;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        return 301 https://example.com/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not what you asked, but get rid of TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 from your list of TLS protocols. Because cybercreeps.

Comment: ok, I will. Thanks

Comment: @Vasile did you got any approach to return 404 for wrong pages ?